# Mac Standard/Non-Admin User reading login history?

Tags: macos, cocoa, authentication, history

I wrote a little program that reading wtmp to show login history (utmpx.h), the problem is it only works when the user is an Admin User, Standard Users of Mac OS X simply can't see any record.

I know wmtp can only be read by admins, so my questions is: are there any alternatives rather than reading wtmp to get login history? Or, is it possible for a Standard User to read the wtmp (or just read the user's own history)?

Thanks and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Can you add more details, such as which functions you are calling (or structures you are using) in `utmpx.h` to figure this out? Are you trying to read directly from the file or are you using the API? Did you read `man utmpx`? Which version of OS X are you using? Which specific file (full path) are you trying to read, and what are its permissions? (run `ls -la <path-to-utmp-file>`; from my reading of the man page it should be in `/var/run/utmpx`)

Comment: Thanks Mike. I have read the man page of utmpx, but it seems the /var /run/utmpx only contains the utmp records but not wtmp. And I used void setutxent_wtmp(int) , getutxent_wtmp(void), endutxent_wtmp(void) in utmpx.h, same as in the source of last. I'm running Lion 10.7.2.

Comment: It seems that apple have moved the wtmp records to ASL. I can view the wtmp logs in Console as an Admin User, but a Standard User can't read that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm on OS X and I don't have wtmp or utmp by default. I do have last, which I seem to be able to run as a non-admin user.

```
another@17:~$ last
uncreative  ttys004                   Wed Oct 26 21:57   still logged in
uncreative  ttys003                   Wed Oct 26 20:55   still logged in
....

another@17:~$ groups
staff com.apple.sharepoint.group.3 localaccounts everyone com.apple.sharepoint.group.1 com.apple.sharepoint.group.2 com.apple.sharepoint.group.4
```

Comment: I have read the source of last, it uses wtmp (getutxent_wtmp). Strange thing is when I run the last command as a Standard User, I can't see any log, it just shows "wtmp begins [current time]",  and I don't know why.

Comment: which version of OS X are you on? Also, how did you add the non-admin account?

Comment: I'm on 10.7.2 Lion, and I created the user in the System Preferences.

Comment: Hmm. It worked for me in Snow Leopard but when I experimented in Lion, I get the same results you are

Comment: Thanks for the information! I have not experimented on Snow Leopard.